# Prevent a Python installation from looking packages up in dist-packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.7

I have Python 3.7 (installed from the deadsnakes PPA) on Ubuntu 18.04. When listing packages with `python3.7 -m pip list` without the `--user` option, it shows packages from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. This is problematic, because the directory actually contains packages for Python 3.6, not for 3.7. What's worse, when importing packages, my 3.7 installation looks up there as well. I would like such imports to fail immediately with a `ModuleNotFoundError`, not at some later point with a much more cryptic error. What can I do to achieve that?

Comment: This is exactly what virtualenv is for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman while technically true, it only isolates single projects, not the whole 3.7 installation (or maybe I misunderstand your point).